# Azure Traffic Manager monitoring status is 'degraded' for Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-traffic-manager

Azure Traffic Manager monitoring status for Endpoints(Azure Application Gateway/WAF)is degraded. Web app behind the Application gateway is healthy and able to access through Traffic Manager.

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Does your application require you to sign in? We've had that before where the probe hits the redirect to sign in and returns a 302.

Comment: No, it does not require any sign-in. My AppGW/WAF is v2. Is there anything related to V2.

Comment: No, still the issue is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, this issue comes only if your listener is *Multisites*. If the listener is *Basic* for app gateway then it works as expected.

The solution, need to set *custom header settings* against the hostname. Like below:

```
hostname:web1.com,newheader:web2.com
```

You also need to set the custom status code range. 
Refer: https://sakaldeep.com.np/1156/troubleshooting-azure-traffic-manager-monitoring-status-is-degraded-for-azure

Comment: Can you clarify what web1.com and web2.com are? Are these the hostnames of the AppGateway? As well your example uses hostname but then in your screenshot you use host which is also what the tooltip suggests. e.g. If your hostname is app.example.com, the custom header is host:app.example.com. This is the format that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can press **F12** to check the Network status of your webpage to determine what status is returned. You also can use [tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-troubleshooting-degraded#troubleshooting) to show the HTTP status code return from the probe URL. An endpoint is unhealthy when any of the following events occur:

- A non-200 response is received (including a different 2xx code, or a 301/302 redirect) or non-any of the responses configured in the Expected status code ranges.
- Request for client authentication
- Timeout
- Unable to connect

Also, If all endpoints in a profile are degraded, then Traffic Manager treats all endpoints as healthy and routes traffic to all endpoints. This behavior ensures that problems with the probing mechanism do not result in a complete outage of your service.

You could verify if any of the above events happen on your side and modify the health probe configuration. Such as the health probe path should have enough logic to identify the endpoint is up or down. Edit expected status code ranges and probe timeout. See more information about [configuring endpoint monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-monitoring#configure-endpoint-monitoring).

Comment: What you said has mentioned MS doc. Both endpoints are degraded and think are working fine but the issue is ' while the endpoint is in the degraded state then it will not switch to other regions in the case of the first region failed'. So endpoint monitoring must be online to failover. Still no luck.

Comment: Followed the [endpoint monitoring status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-monitoring#endpoint-monitor-status), when monitoring status is online, the status of at least one endpoint is Online. No endpoints have a Degraded status. Could you show any screenshots about monitoring status and TM profile configuration? It's better to describe more details about your concerns.

Comment: The status is TM-Enabled, Endpoint-Enabled, Monitoring Status-Degraded, Routing Method- Priority. TM profile configuration - default (port-443, protocol-https, path - /, status code range - 200-299, 301

Comment: When the monitoring status is degraded, do you check the real probe status code via these [tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-troubleshooting-degraded#troubleshooting)? Or refer to [Enable diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-diagnostic-logs) for more information. The degraded status is only meaning that health checks of these endpoints are failing. Not sure what's the real concerns on your side?