# Azure Traffic Manager - Monitor status: Degraded

Tags: azure

I use the Traffic Manager for some of our sites, but today when I add a new profile, it always has a degraded status.

Analyzing the NGINX logs, the request is not reaching any of our servers.

I don't believe it's configuration, as the other profiles are working (and some pointing to the same servers).

I did the troubleshooting as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-troubleshooting-degraded) and it always returns 200.
Invoke-WebRequest
[image]

cURL
[image]

Using this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-diagnostic-logs), I tried to enable logs, but no file is created in storage:
[image]

Traffic Manager configuration:
[image]

Endpoint configuration:
[image]

I'm lost :)
Because other profiles using the same endpoint are online, and the Traffic Manager configuration is simple, nothing complex and it doesn't work.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you try to follow these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189898/azure-traffic-manager-shows-endpoints-degraded-but-they-return-200?rq=2) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60154837/azure-traffic-manager-monitoring-status-is-degraded-for-azure-application-gate#:~:text=The%20solution,%20need%20to%20set%20custom%20header%20settings,need%20to%20set%20the%20custom%20status%20code%20range.).

Comment: I already checked these links. In the print youj can verify that there is no redirection by cURL adn there is the host header in the traffic manager.

Comment: with the [this](https://imgur.com/2m5eWmA) PowerShell code, I can be able to see **logs** in my **storage account**. you can check these [image1](https://imgur.com/3X24H7n) and [image2](https://imgur.com/LEIpsmo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved by changing TLSv3 to TLSv2.